# LocationClient connection and Geofence

Tags: android, gps, android-4.4-kitkat, geofencing, android-geofence

Do you need a connected LocationClient to detect that the user has a left a Geofence?
In my current code I connect my LocationClient, establish a geofence, then disonnect the LocationClient.  However, it sometimes detects that I have left it, but at a much further location outside the Geofence.

Answer (score 2):

An important note on the Google Play GeoFencing API. I've found that the GeoFencing never intelligently retrieves locations from the GPS hardware. The GeoFence API will observe the most accurate location available from the OS or if no recent location reading is available, it will cause a location to be calculated from Wifi / Cellular. (which sucks because cellular is wildly inaccurate and wifi is often unavailable)

So to get at all responsive or accurate results out of the Geofencing API you have to set up your Geofences and then poll the GPS hardware on an interval, not even doing anything with the result received, so that under the surface you are providing worthwhile data to the OS.

This is probably at the core of why your results are so inaccurate. The geofence exit won't  trigger until the OS is sure you're 100% outside the fence - so if a location reading has an accuracy of 500 meters (not improbable when using cell geolocation) and your fence has a radius of 50m you'd have to be at least 550m from your fence point to produce an exit event.

TLDR; Poll the GPS hardware on an interval without doing anything with the result and you'll start getting more accurate geofences.

Comment: Do you happen to know if you I can poll the gps while the application is in the background using a timer?

Comment: Yes, my application does this, raising notifications when a fence is  triggered. Turn by turn direction apps on Android do this same thing.

Comment: Any idea on how to keep your app from being killed in the background doing something like this? I have a broadcast receiver that deals with my geofence enter/exit, but it sometimes gets killed by the OS, like say overnight.

Comment: I think we have similar configurations though I haven't experienced my app being killed like this. Have you scanned the system logs for a clue on what happened to your app during the night? I haven't done alot of testing over very long periods as my application is generally intended for 8-10 hours of usage, but I've had instances run for days at a time during testing.